Mayor precisión para almacenar el tiempo en MySQL
Tengo una tabla en MySQL, esta tabla consta de un campo llamado fecha_creacion y, como lo dice su nombre, ahí se almacena la hora en que el registro es creado en la tabla.
fecha_creacion TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 

esta es la fecha y hora de un registro creado:
2024-05-06 21:10:13

Quiero obtener una mayor precisión; que sea en milisegundos o cualquier otra manera.

Y los milisegundos como para que o que??

"... fecha_creacion y, como lo dice su nombre, ahí se almacena la hora ..." - pues, no, el nombre sugiere una fecha, no una hora. ,Un mejor nombre sería hora_creacion entonces.  :-)

Puedes definir el tipo de dato de la fecha de creación con TIMESTAMP(3) para almacenar fechas con una precision de milisegundos, o TIMESTAMP(6) para una precision de microsegundos... Por ejemplo dada la siguiente tabla de prueba:
create table register (
    registerID integer not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    createdAt timestamp(3) default now(3),
    constraint register_pk primary key (registerID)
);

Al insertar valores sin especificar la fecha, se utiliza el valor por defecto now(3) que devuelve el tiempo presente del sistema operativo donde se esta ejecutando tu servidor MySQL, con una precision de milisegundos.
insert into register (name) values ('Nicholas');
insert into register (name) values ('Francis');

SELECT * from register;


Si obtienes algún error al ejecutar esto, probablemente sea porque tienes una version desactualizada de MySQL.
Aqui puedes encontrar mas informacion al respecto.

Si me ha funcionado, gracias!
